# imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am using a image thumbnailing library (Laravel's [resizer bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/resizer)) which takes a jpg from a directory and uses `imagesx()` to save that image in a different size. This works without error most of the time.

**Problem:** However sometimes when there is a batch of images to be processed, I get the error below. While debugging, I did

```
....
print_r($this->image);
imagesx($this->image);
....
```

**PHP output**

```
Resource id #64Resource id #67Resource id #73Resource id #76Resource id #82Resource id #85Resource id #91Resource id #94Resource id #100Resource id #103Resource id #109Resource id #112Resource id #118Resource id #121Resource id #127Resource id #130Resource id #136Resource id #139Resource id #145Resource id #148Resource id #154Resource id #157Resource id #163Resource id #166

Unhandled Exception

Message:

imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Location:

/home/dev/public_html/bundles/resizer/resizer.php on line 69
Stack Trace:

#0 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(40): Laravel\Error::native(2, 'imagesx() expec...', '/home/dev/publi...', 69)
#1 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(2, 'imagesx() expec...', '/home/dev/publi...', 69, Array)
#2 /home/dev/public_html/bundles/resizer/resizer.php(69): imagesx(false)
#3 /home/dev/public_html/bundles/resizer/resizer.php(81): Resizer->__construct('/home/photos/pu...')
#4 /home/dev/public_html/application/controllers/crawl/cl.php(369): Resizer::open('/home/photos/pu...')
#5 /home/dev/public_html/application/controllers/crawl/cl.php(315): Crawl_CL_Controller->save_photos(Array, 2516533, '2012-09-17 18:4...')
#6 [internal function]: Crawl_CL_Controller->action_crawl_next_item()
#7 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/routing/controller.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/routing/controller.php(285): Laravel\Routing\Controller->response('crawl_next_item', Array)
#9 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/routing/controller.php(165): Laravel\Routing\Controller->execute('crawl_next_item', Array)
#10 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/routing/route.php(153): Laravel\Routing\Controller::call('crawl.cl@(:1)', Array)
#11 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/routing/route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
#12 /home/dev/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(165): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
#13 /home/dev/public_html/public/index.php(34): require('/home/dev/publi...')
#14 {main}
```

Together with the stack trace above, you can see that `$this->image` is `false` right after its `Resource id #166`.

Any idea what may have caused this? I dont understand why it can sometimes be `false`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the mime type for that file isn't being recognised or is not a jpg/jpeg/png/gif.

The $this->image is being set to false on line 196 in resizer.php.

If you can't get it to work, please create an issue on Github so I can follow it up :-)

Comment: I checked out the file's mime type by checking it in the `switch()` part of the code which matches the file's mime types with the ones in Laravel. I believe the error came from GD's inability to handle that particular jpeg file. I switched library and its working now.

Comment: @Nyxynyx - That's great that it's working for you, but how about telling us what you did so you can help someone else?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using **imagesx()** to get *width* of image and **imagesy()** to get *height* of image
you can use **list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imagesource);**